# How to draw stroke(s) outside of an element?

Tags: ios, swiftui

I am working on an overlay effect that consists of 2 strokes, preview of it can be seen below (green strokes)

[image]

So far I was able to achieve it only by using 2 overlay elements like this:

```
    .overlay {
      ZStack {
        RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 18, style: .continuous)
          .inset(by: -2)
          .stroke(.green.opacity(0.2), lineWidth: 4)
        RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: size18, style: .continuous)
          .strokeBorder(.green)
      }
    }
```

But using 2 elements here feels excessive? I was trying to see if there is a simpler solution where I could use single rounded rectangle but force second stroke to be drawn outside of it instead of in the center?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to draw two different shapes in two different ways, so the use of two subviews is appropriate. There are other solutions (for example, using a `Canvas`), but I don’t think any other solution would be simpler.

You could factor out the `RoundedRectangle` if you want, but I wouldn’t say it’s simpler:

```
ZStack {
    let shape = RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 18, style: .continuous)
    shape
        .inset(by: -2)
        .stroke(.green.opacity(0.2), lineWidth: 4)
    shape
        .strokeBorder(.green)
}
```