# How to add a border in SwiftUI with clipShape?

Tags: swift, swiftui

I'm confused how I add a border with a stroke color and line width to a SwiftUI View using clipShape. Basically, I just want to have rounded corners with a border color.

```
Rectangle()
    .frame(width: 80, height: 80)
    .foregroundStyle(.gray)
    .clipShape(
        RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 6)
    )
```

Comment: What's wrong with `.addBorder`?

Comment: try adding `.border(.red, width: 6)`, just before your `clipShape`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unfortunately, you cannot simply apply `.border` in combination with `.clipShape`, because this always draws a square border:

- If `.border` is applied before `.clipShape` then it is clipped at the corners. You notice it more when the corner radius is large.
- If `.border` is applied after `.clipShape` then the corners of the border are square.

So to add a border around a clipped shape, you need to stroke it as a separate operation using the same shape. An overlay works well:

```swift
Rectangle()
    .frame(width: 80, height: 80)
    .foregroundStyle(.gray)
    .clipShape(
        RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 6)
    )
    .overlay(
        RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 6)
            .stroke(.red, lineWidth: 2)
    )
```

[image: Corner]

See the answer to [How to draw stroke(s) outside of an element?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/77707762/20386264) for a way to define the `RoundedRectangle` just once.

Comment: Thank you! That works. It just seems odd to be that you have to define the same shape twice to achieve this result.

Answer (score 1):

The .border() modifier used to have a cornerRadius parameter, but it has been deprecated. So, if you need to round the corner of a border, use the .overlay() modifier with a built-in SHAPE, which can use cornerRadius instead.

Shapes are views, and **.stroke() .strokeBorder()** modifiers can be applied *directly* to shapes and get the desired border. So, as you know, this only works for shapes. If you apply a modifier to shapes, such as .frame(), .foregroundStyle(), or clippedShape(), these are NON-SHAPE VIEWS. So, you can't use stroke to them.
You can use the **.border()** modifier to get a non-rounded corner border or the **.overlay()** modifier to get a desired rounded border for non-shape views. Like this

```
.overlay(
        RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 20, style: RoundedCornerStyle.continuous)
            .stroke(.red, lineWidth: 3)
    )
```

In addition, it's more precise to use the shape you need directly and apply the overlay on it rather than use another shape, clip the desired shape, and then apply the overlay. The clip shape is an extra step. A more concise code that achieves the same effect is this:

```
RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius:  20)
                    .frame(width: 80, height: 80)
                    .foregroundStyle(.gray)
                    .overlay {
                        RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 20, style: RoundedCornerStyle.continuous)
                            .stroke(Color.red, lineWidth: 3)
                    }
```

However, it's easier to do it in this way:

```
RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius:  20)
    .stroke(.red, lineWidth: 3)
    .fill(.gray)
    .frame(width: 80, height: 80)
```

Or this way:

```
RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius:  20)
    .stroke(.red, lineWidth: 3)
    .background(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius:  20).fill(.gray))
    .frame(width: 80, height: 80)
```

Tips: (1) **.stroke()** draws a border right on the frame(half inside, half outside the frame); **.strokeBorder()** draws a border right inside the frame(100% inside and stick to the frame). So, in our eyes, .stroke() draws a larger shape than .strokeBorder when the border is the top layer.

(2) The default RoundedCornerStyle for RoundedRectangle was .circular from iOS 13 to 16 and has been .continuous from iOS 17. The .continuous style is slightly smoother when round corners.

(3) We can conform to the Shape protocol and customize shapes, and then use .stroke().
Build-in shapes include Rectangle, RoundedRectangle, UnevenRoundedRectangle, Capsule, Ellipse, and Circle.
You can play with them like this:

```
UnevenRoundedRectangle(cornerRadii:.init(
                    topLeading: 75.0,
                    bottomLeading: 0.0,
                    bottomTrailing: 75.0,
                    topTrailing: 0.0))
    .stroke(.red, lineWidth: 1.5)
```

[image: Examples]

Answer (score 0):

<del>Simply `.addBorder` within `Rectangle`:</del>

```swift
Rectangle()
    .frame(width: 80, height: 80)
    .foregroundStyle(.gray)
    .clipShape(
        RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 20)
    )
    .overlay {
        RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 20) //<- make the overLay corner same as clipShape
            .strokeBorder(Color.red, lineWidth: 2)
    }
```

**Updated**: As @Benzy pointed out, it will not work with a larger radius, so the above is a workaround.

[image]

Comment: This clips the border at the corners. You see it better if you make the corner radius larger (like 20).

Comment: You're right @BenzyNeez, I didn't notice that, edited. Wow we got the same idea haha