# double border in swiftui container

Tags: swiftui

I am not able to add a bold border follow by a not-bold-border.
[image: bold followed by not-bold-border]

I can do not-bold and then bold border but i dont know if the border a bold border follow by a not-bold-border is possible

this is what i have so far:::

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        EventMatcherCardBorder{
            Text("A")
        }
    }
}

#if DEBUG
struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
#endif

struct EventMatcherCardBorder<Content: View>: View {
    let content: Content
    let CORNER_RADIUS: CGFloat = 50
    
    init(@ViewBuilder content: () -> Content) {
        self.content = content()
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack{
            VStack{
                VStack {
                    VStack{
                        
                        Spacer().frame(height:5)
                        Image("auth_icon")
                            .resizable()
                            .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
                            .frame(height: 50)
                        content
                            .background(Color.white)
                            .padding(10)
                    }
                    .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity)
                }
                .padding(2)
                .overlay(
                    RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: CORNER_RADIUS)
                        .stroke(ThemeColors.dark_blue_2, lineWidth: 8)
                )
            }
            .padding(1)
            .overlay(
                RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: CORNER_RADIUS)
                    .stroke( ThemeColors.dark_blue_3, lineWidth: 6)
            )
        }.padding(15)
        
    }
}

struct ThemeColors {
    static let dark_blue_2 = Color.blue
    static let dark_blue_3 = Color.red
}
```

i didt find a stackoverflow that had the Bold not-Bold border

Comment: Is the picture the desired result or the result of your failed attempt? When you say "A followed by B", do you mean A is the inner border and B is the outer border, or the other way round?

Comment: This post might help: [How to draw stroke(s) outside of an element?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/77707762/20386264)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want a dark border followed by a lighter border, then
use `static let dark_blue_2 = Color.blue.opacity(0.3)` and
add `.padding(4)` after your `.stroke(ThemeColors.dark_blue_2, lineWidth: 8)`
to adjust the location of the inner lighter border as shown in the example code:

```
struct EventMatcherCardBorder<Content: View>: View {
    let content: Content
    let CORNER_RADIUS: CGFloat = 50
    
    init(@ViewBuilder content: () -> Content) {
        self.content = content()
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack{
            VStack{
                VStack {
                    VStack{
                        Spacer().frame(height:5)
                     //   Image("auth_icon")
                        Image(systemName: "house") // <-- for testing
                            .resizable()
                            .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
                            .frame(height: 50)
                        content
                            .background(Color.white)
                            .padding(10)
                    }
                    .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity)
                }
                .padding(2)
                .overlay(
                    RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: CORNER_RADIUS)
                        .stroke(ThemeColors.dark_blue_2, lineWidth: 8)
                        .padding(4) // <-- here, adjust as required
                )
            }
            .padding(1)
            .overlay(
                RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: CORNER_RADIUS)
                    .stroke(ThemeColors.dark_blue_3, lineWidth: 6)
            )
        }.padding(15)
    }
}

struct ThemeColors {
    static let dark_blue_2 = Color.blue.opacity(0.3) // <-- here, adjust as required
    static let dark_blue_3 = Color.red
}
```